# jboss log4j configuration

Tags: jboss, log4j

I have some war, ejb jar applications in jboss 4.2.2 GA, the logging for which is configured in `jboss-log4j.xml`.

Based on the appenders and log location, the logs are getting updated in the expected path and file. But I see, the logs are also getting written into `server.log` with the appender name as identifer something like `[]`.

Any idea about stopping application related log updates into `server.log` and only specific log file path configured in appenders, should only be updated.

Comment: Could you please include your log4j.xml

Answer (score 1):

As Oleg says you should post your log4j file...

Or to try to second guess the issue:

Put an entry in the jboss log4j file (`$JBOSS_SERVER/conf/jboss-log4j.xml` or `$JBOSS_SERVER/conf/log4j.xml` on older versions) to remove your app logging. EG:

```xml
<category name="com.mycompany">
   <priority value="FATAL"/>
</category>
```

Then only fatal error messages from the "com.mycompany" package will be logged to it. OR turn off attaching the "FILE" appender to the root package (at the bottom of the file).

You should then configure an appender specifically for you application packages. Look at the appender examples in the jboss-log4j.xml file.